# Почему не удается сделать загрузочную флешку с помощью ultraiso?

Tags: boot, диск, автозагрузка, dual-boot, iso-образ

Есть DVD с инсталяцией windows xp и кучей программ. При чем если грузится с этого DVD, то в начале появляется меню с выбором действий (установить виндовс, запустить acronis, др.программы... загрузится с live cd)
Сделал iso образ этого DVD и пытаюсь его записать на флешку по этой инструкции с помощью ultraiso: [ссылка](http://ultraiso-club.ru/bootable-usb-drive.html)

Но когда пробую грузится с этой флешки, пишет "ntdetect failed". Что я делаю не так? Как сделать загрузочную флешку - аналог этого DVD?

Comment: видео инструкции на ютубе смотрел?

Comment: А чем плоха инструкция, ссылку на которую я привел в вопросе?

Comment: А у компа часом не UEFI-загрузка?

Comment: Legacy. Dvd грузится норм, а флешка не хочет.